# math.cosh() alternative for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**Problem**

My code works fine in google chrome, however Math.cosh() object is not supported by IE is there an alternative?

```
var coshD = function() {
  var val = 0.4 / 1000;
  var val2 = 60 * val;
  var val3 = siDin();
  var val4 = val2 / val3;
  var total = **Math.cosh**(val4);
  $('#coshD').val(+total.toFixed(6));
  return total;
}
```

I have tried looking over the internet for a solution before but have not found anything. your help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cosh#Polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use the other functions in the math library that are supported by IE. Try this code (tested in IE 11 which did not have cosh):

```
var total = (Math.exp(val4) + Math.exp(-val4)) / 2
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with mathematics behind this function, but obvious approach would be to use polyfill - custom implementation of the feature which is not supported by the browser.

One from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cosh):

```
Math.cosh = Math.cosh || function(x) {
  return (Math.exp(x) + Math.exp(-x)) / 2;
}
```